# Add same product with different sizes to the cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, shopping-cart, reducers

I can add different products as individual arrays and also can increment the quantities if same product is added. But now I need to add same product but with Different size and it should create another new array. Below is the code I am using.. Please help out..!!

```
switch (action.type) {
case ADD_TO_CART:
    const productId = action.product.id;

    if (findIndex(state.cart, product => product.id === productId) !== -1) {
        const cart = state.cart.reduce((cartAcc, product) => {
            if (product.id === productId) {
                // if (product.size === action.size) {
                    cartAcc.push({ ...product, size: parseInt(product.size), qty: parseInt(product.qty) + parseInt(action.qty), sum: (product.discount ? product.salePrice : product.price) * (parseInt(product.qty) + parseInt(action.qty)) }) // Increment qty
                // } else {
                //     cartAcc.push(product)
                // }

            } else {
                cartAcc.push(product)
            }
            return cartAcc
        }, [])

        return { ...state, cart }
    }
    return {
        ...state,
        cart: [
            ...state.cart,
            {
                ...action.product,
                qty: action.qty,
                size: action.size,
                sum: (action.product.discount ? action.product.salePrice : action.product.price) * action.qty
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `findIndex`, is it the `yourArray.findIndex` or your special function?

Comment: it is the special function

`export const findIndex = function (array, cb) {
    if (array) {
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (true === cb(array[i]))
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct however you need to give a unique product ID for each product with specific attributes.
for Example

`Product: { id: 'Nike' size: ['S', 'M', 'L'] color: ['blue', 'white', 'black']}`

your Cart is having multi items where this product example having ID: 'Nike,s,blue'.
each time you try to find this product with that specific ID you will be able to add it as new or Increase it if it already exist.

You may take the same logic with T-shirt 'L' where its ID: 'Nike,L,blue'. it make it a new product and separated.

Briefly: You need to make a unique ID for each product along with its Attributes (you may combine the attributes with the ID based on the Object.values or array where you have the Data).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done, just check for size equality (in findIndex and in the subsequent if):

```
const productId = action.product.id;
const size = action.size;

if (findIndex(state.cart, product => (product.id === productId && product.size === size)) !== -1) {
        const cart = state.cart.reduce((cartAcc, product) => {
            if (product.id === productId  && product.size === size) {
                    cartAcc.push({ ...product, size: size, qty: parseInt(product.qty) + parseInt(action.qty), sum: (product.discount ? product.salePrice : product.price) * (parseInt(product.qty) + parseInt(action.qty)) }) // Increment qty
            } else {
                cartAcc.push(product)
            }
            return cartAcc
        }, [])

        return { ...state, cart }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is giving the error saying 'size' is not defined. do I need to create the const for size also..?

Comment: Awesome.. This is working Thanks... Now I can add same product with "s" size at first time and then with "m" size when button clicked with size selection. But after that if I again want to add "s" size then its making a new entry. It should add the qty to existing size.. {product id is same}

Comment: If you use "s" and "m"" as product sizes, then you should not apply parseInt to this field, you should keep it as a string. I have updated my answer.

Comment: no no.. my sizes are 6, 9, 11.. thats why I used parseInt..

Comment: If you use parseInt, I suggest to replace the === with == in the comparisons. We would need a code sandbox with a minimal example to help you further.

Comment: I think there is some issue with code sandbox.. If you could solve the problem or give the hints, it will be really helpful.

Comment: You've gone this far, I am sure you will succeed finding the issue! Happy coding

Comment: Thanks Louis.. I appreciate your help.!

Comment: I figured it out.. I used array.some() method instead of array.findIndex(). But now for one array I can add only 2 qty if added individually.. It should also add the exsiting one.. I am clueless again

Comment: You should insert console.log in your code in order to track the values of your variables, and find what is wrong. If you feel bold you could even attach your browser's debugger.

Comment: yes.. I console logged the values. When I add the new product it is all ok.. Specific issue is in product.size.. when I again add the same product with single quantity the product.size is matching. And then for the 3rd time it's not.. So why is this discrepancy..?

Comment: Thanks a lot Louis.. Your hit worked..! "I suggest to replace the === with == in the comparisons." Problem solved Fully